# Skip list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, collections, skip-list

I've made an attempt at writing a skip list in Python. I'm using NumPy to generate geometric random variables, but since that's a bit of a heavy dependency to drag around I could easily implement that myself.

I based my implementation on the basic (none of the improvements such as capping node height etc.) algorithm [here](ftp://ftp.cs.umd.edu/pub/skipLists/skiplists.pdf).

What do you think needs improvement?

```
import numpy as np

class SkipList:

    def __init__(self, p=0.5):
        """
        Create a Skiplist object.

        >>>> l = Skiplist()                                  # An empty skip list
        >>>> l = Skiplist.from_iter(zip(range(5), range(5))) # A skip list from an iterable

        """
        self.p = p

        self.head = SkipList.Node()
        self.max_height = 1

        self.__length = 0

    def from_iter(it, p=0.5):
        """
        Create a SkipList from an iterable of (Key, Value) tuples
        """
        s = SkipList(p=p)
        for k, v in it:
            s.insert(k, v)

        return s

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        curr = self.head
        for level in range(self.max_height - 1, -1, -1):
            while curr.forward[level] and curr.forward[level].key < key:
                curr = curr.forward[level]

        res = curr.forward[0]
        if res and res.key == key:
            return res.value
        else:
            raise KeyError("Key {} not found".format(key))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        """
        If the key is already present, the current value will be overwritten with the new value.
        """
        new_node = None
        curr = self.head
        update = [None for _ in range(self.max_height)]
        for level in range(self.max_height - 1, -1, -1):
            while curr.forward[level] and curr.forward[level].key < key:
                curr = curr.forward[level]

            update[level] = curr

        if curr.forward[0] and curr.forward[0].key == key:
            curr.forward[0].value = value
        else:
            height = np.random.geometric(self.p)
            new_forward = [n.forward[l] for l, n in enumerate(update[:height])]

            if height > self.max_height:
                new_forward += [None for _ in range(self.max_height, height)]
                self.head.forward += [None for _ in range(self.max_height, height)]
                update += [self.head for l in range(self.max_height, height)]
                self.max_height = height

            new_node = SkipList.Node(key=key, value=value, forward=new_forward)

            for l, n in enumerate(update[:height]):
                n.forward[l] = new_node

            self.__length += 1

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        curr = self.head
        update = [None for _ in range(self.max_height)]
        for level in range(self.max_height - 1, -1, -1):
            while curr.forward[level] and curr.forward[level].key < key:
                curr = curr.forward[level]

            update[level] = curr

        del_node = curr.forward[0]
        if del_node and del_node.key == key:
            for l, f in enumerate(del_node.forward):
                update[l].forward[l] = f
            self.__length -= 1
        else:
            raise KeyError("Key {} not found".format(key))

    def items(self):
        """
        Generator in the style of dict.items
        """
        curr = self.head.forward[0]
        while curr:
            yield (curr.key, curr.value)
            curr = curr.forward[0]

    def __contains__(self, key):
        try:
            self[key]
        except KeyError:
            return False

        return True

    def __iter__(self):
        curr = self.head.forward[0]
        while curr:
            yield curr.key
            curr = curr.forward[0]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.__length

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if len(self) != len(other):
            return False

        for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(self.items(), other.items()):
            if not (k1 == k2 and v1 == v2):
                return False

        return True

    class Node:
        def __init__(self, key=None, value=None, forward=None):
            if forward is None:
                forward = [None]

            self.key = key
            self.value = value
            self.forward = forward
```

Answer (score 2):

**Remove repetition**

You have almost identical code:

```
def items(self):
    """
    Generator in the style of dict.items
    """
    curr = self.head.forward[0]
    while curr:
        yield (curr.key, curr.value)
        curr = curr.forward[0]

def __iter__(self):
    curr = self.head.forward[0]
    while curr:
        yield curr.key
        curr = curr.forward[0]
```

You may avoid the repetition writing:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for key, _ in self.items():
        yield key
```

---

The nested loops:

```
    for level in range(self.max_height - 1, -1, -1):
        while curr.forward[level] and curr.forward[level].key < key:
            curr = curr.forward[level]
```

Are repeated identical 3 times, extract them into a function.

**Use the `all` built-in**

You do not need a manual for loop in `__eq__`:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if len(self) != len(other):
        return False

    return all(self_pair == other_pair
               for self_pair, other_pair in zip(self.items(), other.items())
```

`all` and avoiding tuple unpacking is closer to how you would describe the function in English (all pairs should be equal)

You may also use `and` instead of a separate `if`

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return len(self) == len(other) and \
           all(self_pair == other_pair
               for self_pair, other_pair in zip(self.items(), other.items())
```

It makes the code even nearer to English (The length should be equal and all pairs should be equal)

Comment: Thanks! I've made the changes. One thing I'm unsure about is that the function I created to replace the repated loop code builds the update list even when it's not necessary (i.e. for __getitem__).